# The girl got excited <by> <with> her new toy

Tags: prepositions

[wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)#Grammatical_function):

> **(1)** *The girl got excited **by** her new toy*.

My variant:

> **(2)** *The girl got excited **with** her new toy*.

Could you explain the difference between "*by*" and "*with*"? Thanks!

Comment: Please also check this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/excited-about-something-or-excited-by-something

Answer (score 2):

You can think of *by*, in this case, in the way she got excited, she got excited due to earn this toy.

Using "with", passes the idea of the feeling that she had when she acquires it, the feeling when she in *his company*, maybe playing with it, using it.

So, *by* is used to express **the way** that she got excited. And *with*, expresses the idea of his  **possession** and the feelings due to it.